# Calculating cumulative sum of rasters in a stack

Tags: raster, terra

I am calculating the cumulative sum of rasters in a stack using methods provided by both `terra` and `raster` packages

First, I try to do it step by step as follows:

```
library(terra)
library(raster)

r <- rast(ncols=9, nrows=9)
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)
s <- c(r, r, r, r, r, r)
s <- s * 1:6
x <- s[[1]]+s[[2]]
x <- x+s[[3]]
x <- x+s[[4]]
x <- x+s[[5]]
rr1 <- x+s[[6]]
```

When using `terra`, the output seem not correct

```
rr2 <- rapp(s, s[[1]], nlyr(s), function(i) max(cumsum(i)))
```

However, when using `raster`, the values seem OK.

```
rs<- raster::stack(s)
rs <- calc(rs, fun = cumsum)
rr3 <- rs[[6]]
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example data

```
library(terra)
#terra 1.6.30    
r <- rast(ncols=9, nrows=9)
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)
s <- c(r, r, r, r, r, r) * 1:6
```

With terra 1.6-30 you can use `cumsum` (there is a bug in the CRAN version that prevents this from working)

```
cumsum(s)
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 9, 9, 6  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 40, 20  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
#source(s)   : memory
#names       : lyr.1, lyr.1, lyr.1, lyr.1, lyr.1, lyr.1 
#min values  :     1,     3,     6,    10,    15,    21 
#max values  :    81,   243,   486,   810,  1215,  1701
```

A work-around is

```
app(s, cumsum)
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 9, 9, 6  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 40, 20  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
#source(s)   : memory
#names       : lyr.1, lyr.1, lyr.1, lyr.1, lyr.1, lyr.1 
#min values  :     1,     3,     6,    10,    15,    21 
#max values  :    81,   243,   486,   810,  1215,  1701
```

But in case you only want the last layer, you can of course do

```
sum(s)
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 9, 9, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 40, 20  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
#source(s)   : memory
#name        :  sum 
#min value   :   21 
#max value   : 1701
```

`rapp` does not apply here, but you could use your formula with `app`

```
app(s, \(i) max(cumsum(i)))
```

You can install terra version 1.6-30 with:

```
install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')
```